# PhpMailer can't seem to send mail to Outlook

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've been trying to make a small E-mail function, so it's possible to send an E-mail to my Outlook from my website. But I'm running into some problems.. 
Do I have to change anything in my `php.ini` (xampp)? and username and password should be my outlook `usn/pass` right?
When I run this .php it says: `echo "Mail Not Sent";`
Can't really see what I'm doing wrong.

```php
   require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail ->IsSmtp();
   $mail ->SMTPDebug = 0;
   $mail ->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail ->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
   $mail ->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
   $mail ->Port = 587; // or 587
   $mail ->IsHTML(true);
   $mail ->Username = "mhoegstrup@company.com";
   $mail ->Password = "XXXX";
   $mail ->SetFrom("mhoegstrup@company.com");
   $mail ->Subject = "Test";
   $mail ->Body = "HEJJ";
   $mail ->AddAddress("mhoegstrup@company.com");
   if(!$mail->Send())
   {
       echo "Mail Not Sent";
   }
   else
   {
       echo "Mail Sent";
   }
```

The file PHPMailer is from: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzlVPBUP5IM8dmpDZ2tEZjdRaEU/view`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try change $mail ->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; to  $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;

Comment: `$mail ->SMTPDebug = 0` is not a good starting point if you want to debug ;-)

Comment: Not echoing an error message after a failed send won't help either! Look at *any* of the examples provided with PHPMailer to see how to do that. You've got an invalid combination of `SMTPSecure` mode and `Port` number - see the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I checked documentation and settings of outlook service:
I realized you just need to set SMTPSecure to `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

> ```
> $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
> ```